# CAD software for creating electro schemes, supporting command line export to SVG

Tags: python, cad, svg, electronics

I am starting to work on project written in python. There will be a database of DXF schemes. Based on input parameters some of these schemes will be modified (translation of texts etc.) with python ezdxf package, then exported to SVG format(right now i am using QCAD commant line tools). These SVG files will be placed to HTML template under each other and with Weasyprint python packages converted to PDF file.

I would like to ask if you know about software which could be used to create electro schemes in DXF format and supports DXF to SVG conversion lunched from python. QCAD is good but I am looking for other options. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest DraftSight for this, as it's open-source, free and very well supported and documented, and has an install base in the millions.

https://www.3ds.com/products-services/draftsight-cad-software/

Caveat:

*I'm **no** coder*, I'm a *tech writer/illustrator, draughter, graphic designer, 3D modeler and architectural designer*, so I approach this from the power-user / designer viewpoint, I *do **not*** approach this question from the coder-how-do-I-plug-into-the-API-and-script-cool-stuff viewpoint.

I can tell you DraftSight reads and writes a range of industry-standard file formats, which do include .dwg .dxf etc, and I've just tested the .svg output and they come out perfectly on my setup on Mac OS.

I have no idea how well documented or public-facing the API is for DraftSight, but I know that there's a blogpost on the draftsigh blog by a dev team member on that topic:

http://blog.draftsight.com/2017/07/19/draftsight-api/

So hopefully this is enough info to get you started if indeed this is a good direction for you.

As a potential alternate, I can also tell you that OnShape is a rapidly-gaining-ground free-to-start, pay-to-make-big 3D engineering tool which is all in-browser based, and is wicked effective in its niche - no idea where to start on the dev side of that, but I know they've been shaking the pillars in the 3D engineering software world pretty loudly.

https://www.onshape.com/

Perhaps this will be of use if you like the look of onshape:

https://forum.onshape.com/discussions/tagged/api/p1